# Javascript/jQuery plugin issue (not updating data attribute)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Before I start I'd like to apologise as I don't use jQuery on daily bases and lack knowledge how it works.

I have been having a hard time using one of the jQuery plugins that I include in the bottom of the body. The problem is live updating DOM data attribute. The script looks like:

```
$('#product-image').elevateZoom(
    { zoomType : "inner", cursor: "crosshair"}
);
```

I utilise data attributes in html:

```
<div id="product-image" data-image="/img/sample/17e.jpg" data-zoom-image="/img/sample/17e.jpg" class=" product grid grid-halfhalf timestwo">
<img  src="/img/sample/17e.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

The problem is, that when I click on the thumbnail, it updates these data attributes, likewise:

```
thumb.addEventListener('click',function() {
                var imgParent = DOM.getId('product-image'); // <-- helper obj
                var img = imgParent.querySelector('img');
                var src = img.getAttribute('src');

                img.src = this.src;

                // imgParent.dataset.image = this.src; <-- tried this as well
                // imgParent.dataset.zoomImage = this.src; <-- tried this as well

                imgParent.setAttribute('data-image', this.src);
                imgParent.setAttribute('data-zoom-image', this.src);

                this.src = src;         

    });
```

Since this is live changing images, zoom does not adjust to data attributes being updated, meaning that it still renders initial image's zoom, not the updated one (from data attr).

How can I force update at this point?

**EDIT:**

I figured it out. To refetch data attribute one has to probably either remove and clone node element, or unbind and remove data:

```
$('#product-image').unbind().removeData();
```

Works like magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that zoom plugin of yours is using `jQuery.data()` to handle attached data, it won't see the changes you make to the data attributes. `jQuery.data()` reads the data attributes from the DOM on first access, and on first access *only*. After that, the attributes are cached. From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5):

> The data- attributes are pulled in the first time the data property is accessed and then are no longer accessed or mutated (all data values are then stored internally in jQuery).

I have had the same problem with jQuery not reading updated attributes, and handled it [like this](https://github.com/hashchange/backbone.declarative.views/blob/2.0.2/src/backbone.declarative.views.js#L328-L368) in one of my plugins. In a nutshell, there is no way make jQuery read the data attributes from the DOM after first access. But you can work around it by updating the jQuery data object, rather than the data attributes of the node, like this:

```
if ( $.hasData( imgParent ) ) {
    $( imgParent ).data( {
        image: this.src,
        zoomImage: this.src,
     } );
}
```

Comment: I used    $('#product-image').unbind().removeData(); on every single click to refetch data, and it works like magic.

Comment: @MaciejSitko `.removeData()` does not make jQuery read the data attributes from the DOM again. On the contrary, the call just sets the data to `undefined`, no matter what the actual values in the DOM are. It just happens to work because of the line @FibreFoX linked to - the plugin ignores the data attributes from now on, and reads the `src` attribute instead. Simply updating the data, as outlined above, would save you that DOM access and be a bit more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the problem is the used plugin, does not have to do anything with jQuery itself.

When running `$('#product-image').elevateZoom(...)` the attribute will be read, and the resulting eventlistener does NOT revalidate these attributes. Changing these attributes after executing that command, is not reflected inside the plugin.

https://github.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom/blob/master/jquery.elevatezoom.js#L44

short answer: its not possible

Comment: Thanks. However, I have managed to reload it using something as crude as 

   $('#product-image').unbind().removeData();

on every click. It works perfectly.

Comment: I should have upvoted your answer because it pinpoints the crucial line in the plugin ... did it now :)